# How to prevent non-power-users with admin rights from accidentally installing adware on community pc

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, malware, windows

I am going to describe my problem and solution to prevent non-power-users installing unwanted software along with other software (adware installed through pre-set checkboxes in a "desired software setup.exe")

We have a community PC where 10+ people have admin rights. (all log in with the same local account)

None of these people are going to delete all the data since they are quite nice.

Some of these people install software on the pc they want to use.

Some software comes with unwanted software no one really wants on our pc. But some users don't know how to uncheck certain checkboxes whilst installing unwanted adware, toolbars, ... (sight)

I was looking for an easy solution that would stop e.g. babylon toolbar, ... being installed on our community pc.

Answer (score 9):

You remove their admin rights.

If they don't know what they're doing, they shouldn't have admin rights anyway, and there is no way to stop an administrative (or root) account from doing whatever they want on the machine.  That is the nature (and indeed, the point) of root/admin.

Comment: The point here is not to stop them from doing what they want but from preventing them doing what they don't want to do anyway.
They want to keep the admin rights since it's a community pc.
This may not apply to the enterprise world but maybe a family-pc where everyone wants to install programs but not everyone knows how to remove checkboxes. It's just a real world scenario..

Comment: @yannis the problem you have is that you're hoping the computer works the way you want it to but hopelessn00b is telling you the way it actually does work. It's a choice you have to make: More Secure and less conveniant to use, or more conveniant and less secure. The two goals are in opposition to one another.

Comment: @RobM yes exactly. I'm not saying that HopelessN00b's answer is wrong. Not at all. The goal here is the pc to be more conveniant. I would have gladly given you a +1 for your comment but since I just registered and have 2 downvotes on my 'how to make it conveniant' answer I can't ;)